# Finding the probability of $y \leq \sin x.$

Tags: probability, random-variables

In the rectangle $[0, \frac{\pi} {2}] \times [0, 1]$ a point $(x, y)$ is chosen at random.

Then what is probability that $y \leq \sin x.$

Comment: The answer is $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser but how? could you elaborate?

Comment: The probability of this event equal area of $y\leq \sin x$/area of $[0,\pi/2] \times [0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to asking what proportion of the rectangle area is under the graph of $y=\sin x$. Which is to say:
$$
\frac{\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0\sin x  dx}{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{2}{\pi}
$$